# Create a route to an existing namespace

Tags: namespace, network-namespaces

I have a namespace with an existing interface in it:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000                          
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00                                                            
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                                                                   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                                                                                                 
26: tapeeaec70b-7c: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000   
    link/ether fa:16:3e:68:65:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                               
    inet 192.168.128.11/24 brd 192.168.128.255 scope global tapeeaec70b-7c                                           
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How could I create a new interface in the root NS so I can access the range 192.168.128.0/24? All examples I can find are creating a new NS and adding a veth peer to it.

Comment: You must show what kind of interface is this existing interface. Use `ip -details link show tapeeaec70b-7c`. If it's a tun/tap interface then there should also be a special program reading injecting packets to it. But it won't be able to communicate anywhere else without additional plumbing... usually done with bridges and/or veth. So if you could explain why you have such config and what is your goal?